# OxyPlot find the selected LineSeries

Tags: selection, oxyplot, lineseries

I have a `PlotModel` with multiple `LineSeries` painted. 
What I'm looking for is a trick to select all the LineSeries which the point, detect by the `MouseDown` event, belongs to.

I've done this:

```
this.MouseDown += CheckIfLineSeriesHasBeenSelected;

private void CheckIfLineSeriesHasBeenSelected(object sender, OxyMouseDownEventArgs e)
{
     switch (e.ChangedButton)
     {
          case OxyMouseButton.Left:
               var series = (LineSeries) this.GetSeriesFromPoint(e.Position, 10);
               series.StrokeThickness = 4;
           break;
      }
 }
```

But in this way the model changes the thickness of only a small part of the entire LineSeries.
Do you have any suggestions? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can search randomly around `e.Position` and select the series:

```
    private void PlotModel_MouseDown(object sender, OxyMouseDownEventArgs e)
    {
        int radius = 5;
        List<LineSeries> ss = new List<LineSeries>();
        searchAndAdd(ref ss, e.Position);
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            double x = rand.Next(-radius, radius);
            double y = rand.Next(-radius, radius);
            ScreenPoint pos = new ScreenPoint(e.Position.X + x, e.Position.X);
            searchAndAdd(ref ss, pos);
        }
        foreach (var s in ss)
            s.StrokeThickness = 8;
        plotModel.InvalidatePlot(false);
    }
    void searchAndAdd(ref List<LineSeries> series, ScreenPoint pos)
    {
        var s = plotModel.GetSeriesFromPoint(pos, 10) as LineSeries;
        if (s != null && series.Contains(s) == false)
            series.Add(s);
    }
```

Note that `radius` determines how far you are going to search. Also note that you should call `plotModel.InvalidatePlot(false);` at the end.